# Firebase Realtime equalTo not working with String like "+123"

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an issue and can't find the answer.
Here is my sample firebase database, with an index on "mobile" :

```
test
 A
  mobile : "+1234567"
 B
  mobile : "+2345678"
```

Now I want to query all node with mobile = "+1234567"

```
test.json?orderBy="mobile"&equalTo="+1234567"
returns : { }
```

but

```
test.json?orderBy="mobile"&startAt="+1234567"
returns :
{
  "A" : {
    "mobile" : "+1234567"
  },
  "B" : {
    "mobile" : "+2345678"
  }
}
```

and

```
test.json?orderBy="mobile"&startAt="+1234567"&endAt="+1234567"
returns : { }
```

What's wrong ? It works fine if I remove all "+" signs (in database + requests) ?!

Comment: I think you are looking for `where` clause not order by.

Comment: orderBy is firebase syntax https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#orderby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to [URL encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the `+` character, meaning show it as `%2B`.

So:

```
test.json?orderBy="mobile"&startAt="+1234567"&endAt="%2B1234567"
```

See my working example here: https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/65924783.json?orderBy=%22mobile%22&equalTo=%22%2B1234567%22

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I thought it could be an encoding issue but couldn't find any documentation.

Comment: do you have a list of all the characters that need to be encoded ? "@" works without encoding.

Comment: I still have an issue : it works great with REST query but doesn't with this : FirebaseManager.getRootRef().child("test").orderByChild("mobile").equalTo("%2B1234567") how to make it work with orderByChild ?

Comment: 1) I'm not sure where the encoding problem comes from, so don't know what needs to be encoded (or even why for that matter). I'm quite sure the problem will disappear if you prefix all values with a non-number character, as I suspect the currently value is being interpreted as a number somewhere along the way. 2) I don't immediately recognize the method calls in that last comment, so can't reproduce. If you have this problem with an /SDK, then please create a post for that specific SDK and not for the REST API.

Comment: Ok thanks, posted the question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65926152/firebase-realtime-javascript-sdk-orderbychild-and-equalto-not-working-with-str