# Firebase Realtime Javascript SDK : orderByChild and equalTo not working with string like “+123”

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Using the Javascript SDK and this sample firebase database, with an index on "mobile" :

```
test
 A
  mobile : "+1234567"
 B
  mobile : "+2345678"
```

Now I want to query all nodes with mobile = "+1234567"

```
firebase.database().ref("test").orderByChild("mobile").equalTo("+1234567").once('value', function(snapshot) {
     console.log(snapshot.val());
});

output : null
```

I asked this exact same question for REST API (resolved) : [Firebase Realtime equalTo not working with String like "+123"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65924783/firebase-realtime-equalto-not-working-with-string-like-123)

But can not get it working with the javascript SDK.

Thanks !

Comment: Works for me here: https://jsbin.com/valotoc/edit?html,js,console
Can you set up a similar repro where it doesn't work?

Comment: It works for me as well, I'm deeply sorry, the database was missconfigured, I forgot I removed the "+" after some REST API and never checked the database since. Thanks a lot Frank

Comment: No worries, glad that you got it sorted. I voted to close the question as not reproducible.